# SSIS: passing sql command as variable to ole db source

Tags: ssis

I have created 2 variables in SSIS, namely ProductValue and SQLQuery. The SQLQuery contain the sql statement as below:

```
"SELECT * FROM Products Where ProductID > " + @[user::ProductValue]
```

When I pass the SQLQuery variable to Ole db source via data access mode = *sql command from variable*, system return the error messages as below:

```
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Source [1]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E14.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Statement(s) could not be prepared.".
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E14  Description: "Incorrect syntax near '+'.".
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to have your SQL Query variable set to EvaluateAsExpression.

If you check the value of the SQL Query Variable in the Variables Grid it should say something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Products Where ProductID > 1
```

If it doesn't then you have not defined your variable properly. The Value of your SQL Query variable should not contain any quotes or +, only the expression should in this case.

Comment: How to "You need to have your SQL Query variable set to EvaluateAsExpression" ?

Comment: @KumarVaibhav it's in the variable properties

Comment: can't the variable be initialized by value at runtime. In my case i am generating the SQL query at run time upon checking conditions and wanted to store them in variable and later that variable to use it in Data flow task... is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into this thread, you can change the setting when selecting "Show advanced editor" (=right click on the Oledb source) and select "Component Properties" tab and switch "AccessMode" to "SQL Command From Variable".

Answer (score 0):

Put the command like this: 
"SELECT * FROM Products Where ProductID > " + (DT_STR, 10, 1252) @[user::ProductValue] + ""