# SSIS - use full resultset of execute sql task as input to another execute sql task

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package with two `Execute SQL Tasks`, the first one has a simple `select` statement to select a single column from a table, the result set is an `ID` column which I have to use as input to the second `Execute SQL Task` to get records from another table which matching `IDs`. Basically I have to implement following SQL statement in SSIS:

```
SELECT * FROM TableB WHERE ID IN
(
   SELECT ID FROM TableA
)
```

How can I configure the second `Execute SQL task` to use the result set of first `Execute SQL task` as input to execute an SQL statement like mentioned above?

Comment: so why don't make single task then

Comment: It sounds like you try do to what is usually done using a `Data Flow` and you should be able to combine your 2 tasks into 1 just by creating a query joining the two tables.

Comment: @Filburt I did not mention this in the question..`TableA` is present on an `MSSQL server` and `TableB` is present on an `Oracle Database server`thats why I am trying to do this with two Execute SQL tasks, is that possible?

Comment: You could solve this by creating a Linked Server connection to your Oracle db. This would allow you to query across both databases.

Comment: @Filburt any other way to do this without creating a linked server? I want to able to manage this in the SSIS package itself..

Comment: A possible solution w/o a Linked Server would be pulling your `Table A` using a `DataFlow` and joining your `Table B` using a [Lookup Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation) or pulling both tables and use a [Merge Join Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation). However a Linked Server query likely has far better performance. Overall the solution depends on the number of records you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query a database based on result of query from another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746258/query-a-database-based-on-result-of-query-from-another-database)

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to populate an object variable with the result of the first Execute SQL Task.

Then have a Script Task which loops through the object variable and dynamically builds the SQL String for the second Execute SQL Task, and puts that into a string variable.

Then finally, the second Execute SQL Task uses the string variable for its SQL query.