# How to filter on SSIS from Oracle Source

Tags: sql-server, oracle, visual-studio, ssis

I am using SSIS to pull the data from Oracle database (OLE DB Source) to SQL server (OLE DB Destination).

I'm struggling to filter the data on Oracle level.

The requirement is to read the ID in SQL database and fetch those ID's from Oracle database. The ID is available in SQL server.

How to apply the filter from SQL to Oracle database level?

Comment: For example, you can use "Merge Join" component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Query a database based on result of query from another database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43746258/query-a-database-based-on-result-of-query-from-another-database)

See the post with LoopUp Transformation.
"This is a classic case for using LookUp Transformation. First, use a OLE DB Source to get data from the first database. Then, use a LookUp Transformation to filter this data-set based on the ID values from the second data-set. Here is the steps for using a LookUp Transformation:"

Comment: Thanks perry. I was able to meet the requirements using LookUp Transformation. The solution provided is working as expected.